# Equation gives a constant value of x?

Tags: functions

The given question is :

**Find Maximum value of $f(x) +f(\frac{1}{x}) =\frac {1}{x}$
, $x \in$ domain of f**

I put $x=\frac {1}{x}$  to get $f(x) +f(\frac{1}{x}) =x$
Now from the above equations I get $x=\frac {1}{x}$

This should imply that $ x=1  or -1$ .
But I can put any value of x in the given equation, but my solution gives me this weird result.

Does this imply something different or have I misunderstood this result?
Sorry if the question seems weird or doesn't make sense, but I am confused by this result. I've tried to explain what I think as much as I could.

Comment: it doesn't seem to make sense. if the function's value is +1 or -1, then $f(x)$ + $f(\frac{1}x)$ must be +2 or -2. But, $\frac{1}x$ is need not be +2 or -2. that is a contraction. looks like the function is not possible. or the domain is {-1} or {1}

Comment: clearly $f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(-1) = \frac{-1}{2} $. I request you to check if you want to find maximum value of $f(x)$. I think you have a typo there.

Comment: I've posted the question as it was.The answer is 1/2

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious from the way the question is worded that the domain of $f$ is important. Trying to make sense of the question, suppose we take it as implicit in the question that (1) if $f$ is defined for $x$, then it must be defined for $\frac{1}{x}$, (2) the domain of $f$ is as large as possible.

Now we have that if $f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x}$, then we must also have $f(\frac{1}{x})+f(x)=x$, and hence $x=\pm1$. That means that we must have $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(-1)=-\frac{1}{2}$. So the maximum value assumed by $f$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.